# In Azure Functions, can I combine a C# HttpTrigger with a Python HttpTrigger

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I have a C# Function app that picks up multiple files and directories per client and uploads that data to Azure Blob Storage. I have a different Azure Function app written in Python that picks up those files from blob storage using a TimerTrigger. To process these files in real-time I'd like to have the C# application communicate with the Python application. Is it possible to have the C# app post to HTTP and set up an HttpTrigger in the Python app to process the files when they're ready?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can change the trigger for your python function a make it httptrigger. So at the end of your first fuction when the blob is create you can put in a call to the httptrigger of the python fuction.

A good practice may be to queue the message, And then have the current python function processing the blobs from the QueueTrigger.

You can use the Storage Queue or the service bus to do it.

So your at the end of the c# function you will put a message on a queue, and then the python function will get triggered for that message and it will process the file

Comment: Why would a queue message be better practice? Is it possible if I make HTTP requests concurrently to separate Python function apps, they won't execute? I thought wait methods were inherently built into HttpTriggers. I'm can't find any documentation on Storage Queue. Using service bus would allow the C# function to communicate with the Python function?

Comment: Like simon say in the other response, f the uploaded blob is large and takes time to process, the http call will give you a timeout. So to make the process  So to avoid that you will comunicate through a queue:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-trigger?tabs=csharp. Depending on your needs choose one or the other: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted

Comment: sorry I might be misunderstanding the HttpTrigger, but I thought that I could just send the http request to my Python function which would trigger the Python function to run a Python script to pick up and process the data using the Python `azure.storage.blob` library. The HttpTrigger only would tell the Python function to execute and the work would be done in the `__init__.py` script which is limited to 10 minutes and 1.5 GB of memory.

Comment: Maybe, when you make a http call you c# function will be waiting for the answer of your python function. So unless the python function takes very little time your c # function will be waiting for  his answer and will throw a timeout. If your python function only wake up another diferent process, that will work and his own,  and ends very quickly yes, you can use the httptrigger

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since both Azure Functions are reachable over a dedicated hostname `http://<yourapp>.azurewebsites.net/api/<funcname>`, you can simply set up an `HttpClient` in your C# Azure Function and send requests to your Python Azure function (given that you added a Http trigger to your Python function)

If those files are large, it may still be a better idea to go over Blob Storage (because you can easily make use of concepts like [file streaming](https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip76.html#uploading-and-downloading-a-stream-into-an-azure-storage-blob)). In this case you can set up a [blob trigger in your Python app](https://github.com/yokawasa/azure-functions-python-samples/blob/master/v2functions/blob-trigger-cosmosdb-out-binding/__init__.py). This trigger will fire - almost - instantaneously (given that your Azure Function didn't run idle and does a [cold start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#cold-start)) so no need for a time trigger.

Comment: I don't think it would be possible to use blob triggers because one client might have 10 directories and 10 different files in each directory. I don't want to process those files until all 10 files are in blob storage. The data processing is done in the Python script so the size of the azure.storage.blob library, so the size of the blob shouldn't matter.